# Using XPath and XML syntax

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, xpath, .net-4.5

I am creating an XML parser which will create a lot of "ugly" code and I would really like to get the hang of the `XPath` syntax.

Here is a sample of my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

    <!-- This is the application template. Replace 'TemplateController' to
         move the application to another application space. -->
    <Application Name="TTS_AHC_OSC_21463" Type="Application">
    <fs>10</fs>

    <Subcomponents>
        <Subcomponent Name="CDPEngine" 
                      Model="CDPEngine"
                      src="Components\CDP\CDPEngine.xml">
        </Subcomponent>
        <Subcomponent Name="Messenger"
                      Model="Messenger"
                      src="Components\CDP\Messenger.xml">
        </Subcomponent>
        <Subcomponent Name="WebServer"
                      Model="WebServer"
                      src="Components\CDP\WebServer.xml">
        </Subcomponent>
        <Subcomponent Name="MessengerIOServer"
                      Model="MessengerIOServer"
                      src="Components\CDP\MessengerIOServer.xml">
        </Subcomponent>
```

I would in this case want a query to get all the attributes names and type and sort them into an already defined struct.  So how can this be done. Can anybody please help me with this, I am really having trouble with getting into the XPath syntax and would really appreciate it.

Code example

```
 nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
 XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
 NodeIter = nav.Select("/Subcomponents?????");
```

Comment: I edited your question to show the correct xml. Before you post, do make sure that all your text is in the preview or the question will look really odd. You can look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) for more info on formatting

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get all subcomponents, u can try with

```
XPATH = "//Subcomponents/Subcomponent"
```

TO get the first sub compoenent,

```
   XPATH = "//Subcomponents/Subcomponent[1]"
```

Xpath syntax can be found in

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

You can dynamically verify the XPATH using following online tool,

http://www.xpathtester.com/

Comment: There are some people who downvote any response that refers to w3schools. I've no idea why. It has a bad reputation because it simplifies things, sometimes excessively, but for people like this poster who clearly aren't prepared to read the real specs or buy a textbook, it's a useful resource.

Comment: Thanks this works as it should, I was missing one / in my queries.. So thats why I could not get it to work

Comment: someone made downvote for this answer, if it really works, make a upvote, so that it would useful

Comment: I had quickly down-voted it without explanation (I had to leave abruptly) because the *original* test was just *you can test xpath using this link* which did not answer the question.  Much like the [answer from Andrey0472](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18844185/209259).

Comment: w3schools is never a good resource (which is why I will certainly downvote any post linking to it). How can you call a site that teaches people to write code vulnerable to SQL injection a good site for *anyone*? Especially for beginners it's a horrible site. Here's a proper XPath reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath

Comment: @ThiefMaster : For the novice dev , it is required to be simple. No one can goto sql injection without reading what is basic sql connection. None of resource is bad resource. it is based on the person who takes it..

Comment: So you think it's better to teach someone how to use PHP/MySQL in a highly insecure way without even mentioning that it's insecure right on that page?!

Comment: @MichaelKay Really it is not the simplification why people hate that site. It's all the terrible practices and vulnerable code on there. See also my related comment from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856012/php-arrays-foreach-loop-to-html-table?noredirect=1#comment27823127_18856111